# AngularJS $watch not working in if-block

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement, angularjs-scope, angularjs-watch

I figured out, that my angular script is working:

```js
$scope.CurrentUser = null;
$scope.DatePicker = new Date();
$scope.$watch('DatePicker', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue > new Date())
        $scope.DatePicker = new Date();
}, true);
```

```html
<div>
    <input data-ng-model="DatePicker" type="date" id="datepicker" />
</div>
```

but not if I add an if-statment:

```html
<div data-ng-if="!CurrentUser">
    <input data-ng-model="DatePicker" type="date" id="datepicker" />
</div>
```

Try it:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWBEVM

But I don't understand why. Is there a known issue? Can anybody help?

Comment: `ng-if` create her own scope, so _DatePicker_ inside not avail in scope in controller

Comment: as long as you're not changing the DatePicker in the if-statement, they are syncronous... so, the sope seems to be the same

Comment: that's how work prototypal inheritance: you can read paernt properties, but when you try write - you create own property instead change in parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

> This directive creates new scope.

so, in your case

```
<div data-ng-if="!CurrentUser">
    <input data-ng-model="DatePicker" type="date" id="datepicker" />
</div>
```

`DatePicker` here added in `ng-if` scope and not scope from controller.

for solving, you can use `$parent` property

```
<div data-ng-if="!CurrentUser">
    <input data-ng-model="$parent.DatePicker" type="date" id="datepicker" />
</div>
```

Or apply "dot rule"

```
<div data-ng-if="!CurrentUser">
    <input data-ng-model="data.DatePicker" type="date" id="datepicker" />
</div>
```

and in js

```
$scope.data = { DatePicker : new Date() };
$scope.$watch('data.DatePicker', function (newValue, oldValue) {
...
```

See a bit more about inheritance scope in [wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

Sample

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('BodyCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.CurrentUser = null;
  $scope.DatePicker = new Date();
  $scope.data = { DatePicker : new Date() } ;
  $scope.$watch('DatePicker', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue > new Date())
      $scope.DatePicker = new Date();
  }, true);
  $scope.$watch('data.DatePicker', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue > new Date())
      $scope.data.DatePicker = new Date();
  }, true);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="BodyCtrl">
  <div>
    <span>scope id: {{$id}}</span>
    <input data-ng-model="DatePicker" type="date" id="datepicker" />
  </div>
  <div data-ng-if="!CurrentUser">
    <span>scope id: {{$id}}</span>
    <input data-ng-model="DatePicker" type="date"  />
  </div>
  <div data-ng-if="!CurrentUser">
    <span>scope id: {{$id}}</span>
    <input data-ng-model="$parent.DatePicker" type="date" />
  </div>
  <hr/>
  <div>
    <span>scope id: {{$id}}</span>
    <input data-ng-model="data.DatePicker" type="date" />
  </div>
  <div data-ng-if="!CurrentUser">
    <span>scope id: {{$id}}</span>
    <input data-ng-model="data.DatePicker" type="date"  />
  </div>
  
</div>
```